# JavaScript errors when calling a page through a Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My page works fine if i navigate to the page `http://localhost/abintegro/tests/sjt/1/index.html`  however when I call the page via Ajax I get this error in inspect element console.

**Error**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined
>
> ```
> at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:6:21)
> at j (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js?_=1476785885327:2:29948)
> at k (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js?_=1476785885327:2:30262)
> ```

within `index.html` if i comment out the function bellow the error is no more, however I need the function for the page to work.

**My function**

```
( function($, undefined) {

            $(function() {

                var test = new Test({

                    testName: "Situational Judgement Test 1",
                    dataURL : "./getresultshtml.php",
                    sendEmailURL: "./sendresultsbyemail.php",
                    contentFolder : "./",
                    solutionURL: "../../../content/f/id/21/",
                    userID: 0,
                    courseItemID: 42,
                    XMLFile: "exam.xml",
                    isStandalone: false
                });

                test.start();
            });
        }(jQuery));
```

the Ajax call in `script.js` is as follows.

(once `index.html`is called this way I get the error above)

**The Call**

```
  $("#test3").click(function (event) {
    $.post(
        "tests/sjt/1/index.html",
        function (data) {
            $('.stage2').html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

**//////////////Update//////////////////////**

**Test if used in a external file**

```
    function Test(settings){

    var defaults = {

        testName: "",
        dataURL: "",
        sendEmailURL: "",
        contentFolder: "",
        solutionURL: "",
        downloadURL: "",
        timesTaken: 0,
        userID: 0,
        courseItemID: 0,
        XMLFile: "",
        isStandalone: false
    };

    //merge defaults and settings
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, settings);

    //module fields
    this.testData = null;

    //set up main test objects
    this.eventHub = new EventHub();

    this.Loader = new Loader(this.eventHub, this.settings);

}

Test.prototype.start = function(){

    var context = this;

    //load xml data and start test when data returns
    this.eventHub.subscribeOnce(this, "loader/xml", function(data){

        //get returned data object
        context.testData = data;
        context.settings.testType = data.testType;

        //initialise the test runner
        context.Runner = new Runner(context.eventHub, context.settings, context.testData);
        context.UI = new UI(context.eventHub, context.settings);
        context.Data = new Data(context.eventHub, context.settings);

        //start preload of images and subscribe to loaded event
        context.Loader.preloadImages(context.testData.questions);

        //show intro screen
        context.UI.prepareIntro(context.testData.introText);

    });

    this.Loader.loadXML(this.settings.XMLFile);

}
```

Comment: What is `Test`? and where is it defined?

Comment: have added Test code that is referenced in a different js file

Comment: That's cool, but you're still missing the `Test` constructor.

Comment: Sorry, just seen. just added

Comment: Can you use something like chrome dev tools to find the point at which the error occurs? And then go back up the call stack?

Comment: Yes, I can do that and feed some more information into the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125993/discussion-between-evolutionxbox-and-benjamin-oats).

Comment: Would need to see the order these things appear in. Are you trying to call Test before it has been declared?

Comment: hey @daveyfaherty, im only left with one error now. my exam.xml is not found 404. ill try and solve this then answer the question if i fix it

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved the problem.

I had the js script CDN refrences within `http://localhost/abintegro/tests/sjt/1/index.html`

as im calling the index page within `get.php` i just added the script calls to the php file rather the HTML file and it solved the problems.